# Input time with 15 minutes step

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, time, bootstrap-vue

I have this input time component and I would like the minutes to be marked in steps of 15... currently as I wrote it doesn't work... is there a solution?

```
 <b-form-input
    minutes-step="15"
    type="time" >
 </b-form-input>
```

Among other things, I also did a test with a normal input without using bootstrap and using "step" but still it doesn't work ... if I write 08:23 it makes me do it.
I would like to find a solution that rounds off the minutes, like if I write 8:13 it takes me back to 8:15. or if I write 8:21 it brings me back to 8:30.
I don't know if I've been clear, I don't even know if it's feasible, I've tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the right attribute but not on the right component.

The form-input component doesn't have `minutes-step` listed in its properties.

You should try using the "Form Timepicker" component that seems to fit better with your need, with the `minutes-step` option like so :

```
<b-form-timepicker v-model="value" locale="en" minutes-step="15"></b-form-timepicker>
```

Comment: unfortunately the bootstrap timepicker I tried it and it works terrible... they need to improve it a lot! there is no possibility to manually write the time as in the input time, so in practice what I want is not feasible... thanks for the answer!